# SQL Server : not inserting date when date is already present in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I do not want user to insert the date which he already get inserted in past in table.

My query is working in below cases but in one case it get fails, and in query I return an integer value if it is greater then 0 then I do not allow user to enter the dates.

In database already inserted dates are :

- Start date : 1 April 2016 and     End date :   30 April 2016
- Start date : 1 May 2016 and   End date :   31 May 2016

Below cases

```
            Start Date              End Date
Case 1)      1 march 2016           23 march 2016    working
Case 2)      1 june 2016            15 june 2016     working
Case 3)     15 april 2016           15 may  2016     NOT working
```

Date time format is: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

This is my query

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
FROM 
    [dbo].[CandidateExperience]
WHERE 
    ([CandidateID] = 50) 
    AND ([CandidateExperienceID] <> 118) 
    AND ([DeletedBy] IS NULL) 
    AND (NOT ((('2015-04-15 00:00:00' <[StartDate]) OR ('2015-04-15 00:00:00' > [EndDate]))
        OR (('2015-04-30 00:00:00' > [EndDate]) OR ('2015-04-30 00:00:00'< [StartDate]))))
```

Comment: Post the query which you have tried

Comment: get the minimum start date and maximum end date and use these two values to compare.

Comment: Mukund sir can u modify above query

Comment: Hi @MayurSingh you don't need to call us sir, you know ...

Answer (score 4):

Your `OR` logic is a bit messed up. When you have those in a `NOT` it ends up meaning that if any one of those is true then the whole thing will be evaluated as false - which means that you won't get any rows back. I'm also not sure why you're checking the dates that you are, since they don't match what's in your test case.

Instead, try:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS A1
FROM
    dbo.CandidateExperience
WHERE
    CandidateID = 50 AND
    CandidateExperienceID <> 118 AND  -- Good old ID 118
    DeletedBy IS NULL AND
    (
        ('2015-04-15 00:00:00' > StartDate AND '2015-04-15 00:00:00' < EndDate) OR
        ('2015-05-15 00:00:00' > StartDate AND '2015-05-15 00:00:00' < EndDate) OR
        ('2015-04-15 00:00:00' = StartDate AND '2015-05-15 00:00:00' = EndDate)
    )
```

Comment: Hi @Tom H above query return me 0 for date start date : 1 april 2015 and end date : 30 april 2015. these date exist in table

Comment: but for date 15 april 2015 as start date and 15 May 2015 as end date is working fine

Comment: I guess that brings up an important question. Which end of the dates should be allowed to equal the next or previous range? For example, does one range end on the start of the next range or should it end a day before (or a millisecond before)? I'll assume that both ends can match the range on each side and fix the query appropriately.

Comment: basically i take the time in DateTime data type of column as  00:00:00.i.e for start date : 2015-04-01 00:00:00.000 and for end date : 2015-04-30 00:00:00.000. User not allow to insert the date 1april 2015 and 30 april 2015 as these are already exist

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that uses a sub-query so you can define the date ranges of your existing records and confirming none of the records are within that set of ranges.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
FROM [dbo].[CandidateExperience] C
WHERE ([CandidateID] = 50)
    AND ([CandidateExperienceID] <> 118) 
    AND ([DeletedBy] IS NULL) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '4/1/2016') AS [D1], CONVERT(DATE, '4/30/2016') AS [D2]
            UNION ALL SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '5/1/2016') AS [D1], CONVERT(DATE, '5/31/2016') AS [D2]
            ) Existing (StartDate, EndDate)
        WHERE (C.StartDate <= Existing.EndDate AND C.EndDate >= Existing.StartDate)
            -- Assumes C.StartDate <= C.EndDate and that C.StartDate and C.EndDate do not have times (all 12am)
    )
```